# concept of local base at a point of a topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I don't understand the concept of local base at a point of a topological vector space. What is the meaning the requirement that  any neighbourhood of a point contains some collection from the local base ?

I am not able to match this with the usual concept of basis of a topology.

Comment: It's a "neighbourhood basis", maybe you are acquainted with that term.

Comment: And if you know what a first-countable space is, you know the concept, if not the name.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't know about neighbourhood basis also. I don't understand the term "basis" here. How is it related to the usual concept of basis for topology/linear algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concepts of basis in linear algebra and topology are rather unrelated. The common trait is that you can construct a larger structure in a simple way from a basis.

- You get the vector space by taking the linear combinations of the basis vectors.
- You get the topology by taking the unions of sets in the basis.
- You get the filter of neighbourhoods of a point by taking the supersets of the sets in the neighbourhood basis (local basis).

The term "basis" signifies that the family is in some sense fundamental, you get the whole structure by building on the basis.

Comment: why is it superset ? It should be defined as any neighbourhood around that point is union of some sets from local base (like the usual basis interpretation). Why is it defined in a more general way ?

Comment: It's more useful with just supersets. Then you can have neighbourhood bases consisting of closed neighbourhoods, or of compact neighbourhoods, or, particularly important in the context of topological vector spaces, of balanced or convex and balanced neighbourhoods (of $0$). Not every neighbourhood is a union of such sets.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to understand a definition it is often good to ask yourself why the definition is needed, in what way does it make our life simpler. In the case of topological vector spaces the local base notion is mainly invented because the topology on a topological vector space is translation invariant. What do I mean by this?  Well if you take an open set $U$ in a topological vectorspace, then $aU$ and $a+U$ are  open iff $U$ is open for all scalars $a$. Hence if we wish to determine a basis on a topological vector space $X$ it suffices to determine a base locally at a single point (say $0$). That is it suffices to find a collection of sets $(O_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$, $0 \in O_\alpha$ all $\alpha$, such that for each open set $U$ containing $0$, there is a $\alpha \in A$ such that $U\supset O_\alpha$.